# @XmlSchema: "annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration"

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

2.11 and java7. I'm trying to annotate my package with `@XmlSchema` as seen below.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;

@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
@XmlRootElement(name="urlset")
public class Urlset {

    private String name;

    @XmlElement
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

However I'm getting this compiling error, "annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration"

Does anybody know why this might be happening happening?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@XmlSchema` annotation is a *package* annotation, so put it in a file called `package-info.java`, located in the same source directory as `Urlset.java`, like so:

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
```

Remove that same annotation from your `Urlset` class.

Comment: I'm sorry it was there, I missed it while posting the question. Still an issue.

Comment: Where would I find package-info.java?

Comment: @CodeJunkie - create it in the same source directory as `Urlset.java`

Comment: Okay lastly once I create package-info.java, do I still need to add the @XmlSchema annotation to UrlSet?

Comment: @CodeJunkie - remove it from your `UrlSet` class definition.